# Having trouble populating listview box with vendor info

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When the form loads there is  a combo box where you select a GL account. Once one is selected, then I click the Get Vendor button to load the vendor information. I'm having problems with the code mainly on the form.vb. I need to populate the listview box with the vendor information and I'm not sure what I did wrong. I have referenced the payables class library etc. Getting error at vendor.count on form.vb. I haven't input the database info on Payables.DB b/c I'm not sure what it yes. Thanks.

```
    Public Class Vendor


Dim m_VendorName As Integer
Dim m_FirstName As String
Dim m_LastName As String
Dim m_City As String
Dim m_State As String



Public Sub New()

End Sub



Public Property VendorName() As String
    Get
        Return m_VendorName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        m_VendorName = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property FirstName() As String
    Get
        Return m_FirstName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        m_FirstName = value
    End Set
End Property




Public Property LastName() As String
    Get
        Return m_LastName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        m_FirstName = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property State() As String
    Get
        Return m_State
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_State = value

    End Set
End Property

Public Property City() As String
    Get
        Return m_City
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_City = value
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

```
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Public Class VendorDB

```
Public Shared Function GetVendors() As List(Of Vendor)
    Dim vendorList As New List(Of Vendor)
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = PayablesDB.GetConnection
    Dim selectStatement As String =
        "SELECT VendorName, FirstName, Last Name, State, City " &
        "FROM Vendor " &
        "ORDER BY Description"
    Dim selectCommand As New SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection)
    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader()
        Dim vendor As Vendor

        Do While reader.Read
            vendor = New Vendor
            vendor.VendorName = (reader("VendorName")).ToString
            vendor.FirstName = reader("Firstname").ToString
            vendor.LastName = (reader("LastName")).ToString
            vendor.State = (reader("State")).ToString
            vendor.City = (reader("City")).ToString
            vendorList.Add(vendor)
        Loop
        reader.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        Throw ex
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try
    Return vendorList
End Function
```

End Class

```
   Public Class GLAccount

Private m_Description As String

Public Sub New()

End Sub

Public Property Description() As String
    Get
        Return m_Description
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        m_Description = value
    End Set
End Property

    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Public Class GLAccountDB

```
Public Shared Function GetGLAccountList() As List(Of GLAccount)
    Dim accountList As New List(Of GLAccount)
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = PayablesDB.GetConnection
    Dim selectStatement As String =
        "SELECT Description " &
        "FROM GLAccounts " &
        "ORDER BY Description"
    Dim selectCommand As New SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection)
    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader()
        Dim account As GLAccount
        Do While reader.Read
            account = New GLAccount
            account.Description = reader("Description").ToString
            accountList.Add(account)
        Loop
        reader.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        Throw ex
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try
    Return accountList
End Function
```

End Class

Now this is what I have referred to the payables(form and validator class)

```
    Public Class Validator
Public Shared Function IsPresent(control As Control) As Boolean
    Dim comboBox As ComboBox = CType(control, ComboBox)

    If comboBox.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show(comboBox.Tag.ToString & " is a required field.")
        comboBox.Select()
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If

End Function
```

End Class

```
     Payables
```

Public Class Form1
    Dim vendorList As List(Of Vendor)
    Dim accountList As List(Of GLAccount)

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    LoadComboBoxes()

End Sub

Private Sub LoadComboBoxes()
    accountList = GLAccountDB.GetGLAccountList
    cboAccounts.DataSource = accountList
    cboAccounts.DisplayMember = "Description"
End Sub


Private Sub btnGetVendors_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetVendors.Click
    Dim vendorList As List(Of Vendor)
    Try

        If Vendor.Count > 0 Then
            vendorList = VendorDB.GetVendors()

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("All invoices were paid in full")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub



Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Where your doing Vendor.Count is your issue....what are you needing to check here? Vender is your class not a collection...

Comment: I guess what I was thinking is that if the GL acccount selected had nothing to be paid it wouldn't be on there..kind of like an old program I was running. Would taking that out and doing something like : Do While VendorName.selected.item.add(Name.text)

Comment: I took that out and am now just getting build errors where I haven't filled in the connection info on Payables.db (obviously). Other than that do I need other code under the btnGetVendors_Click otehr than vendorList = Vendor.DB.GetVendors() ?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do (accomplish).

Comment: I need to populate the list view box with vendorname, contact first name, city, and state, when the get vendors button is clicked.In VendorDB I might neeed to change it to GetVendors(ByAccountDescription) then add a parameter after from vendor ---where for account description

Comment: then under button get vendors add wher vendorList=VendorDB.GetVendors(ByAccountDescription) then fill in list view ex. lstViewDescription.Items.Add(Vendor.VendormName),lstViewDescription.Items.Add(Vendor.State) etc?...basically I need to get the vendor info after account is selected by the user and display it